# Accentuation problem with some words

Tags: accents, input-encodings

Well, I open a document .tex that uses this preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and the font codification is UTF-8. The problem is that some, just some, words are not accentuated, and in the place of the accent, a question mark like this �, appears. Here are some examples:

```
Word on the document (wrong)              correct word
         n�mero                              número
        Estat�sticas                      estatísticas
```

Is there any way to solve this problem without having to rewrite all the words?

Comment: Are you referring to the output generated when you compile the document, or the input contained within the `.tex` file when viewed in your editor? If it is the latter, which editor are you using?

Comment: Could you copy and paste the words in question from your `.tex` file? If I compile a document with your preamble and the words taken from your "correct word" column, everything works fine.

Comment: It seems that your editor is using an encoding different from `utf8` (the encoding of your document). Please make sure that both encodings are the same.

Comment: @Werner I am referring to the .tex as a input; it was not generated by me. I'm using TeXMaker, by TexLive.

Comment: @Jake Well, as a matter of fact, the words that I pasted on the first column are from the .tex file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) (or any editor for that matter) should be configured in order to render the correct input, as well as the corresponding output. The following is taken from the [Texmaker documentation](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION01):

> **1.1 Configuring the editor**
>
> Before compiling your first document, you must set the encoding used
>   by the editor ("Configure Texmaker" -> "Editor" -> "Editor Font
>   Encoding"). Then, you should use the same encoding in the preamble of
>   yours TeX documents (example: `\usepackage[latin]{inputenc}`, if you
>   use the "ISO-8859-1" encoding for the editor).
>
> Note: while opening a file, you're warned if the document can't be
>   decoded correctly with the default encoding and the program lets you
>   choose an other encoding (without modifying the default encoding).

Comment: Thank you @Werner! Is the any way to convert a .tex file between encondings, or a encoding that accept more than one style os characters? Daily I use UTF8.

Comment: I am not very familiar with input encodings, since I use TeXnicCenter that doesn't provide that functionality.

Comment: As a matter of information, if the operational system used is ubuntu, the gedit can be used to convert between encodings; its just "save as" the document, and then choose the encoding.

Comment: @Rodrigo: there's a command line program called [`iconv`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.1.html) which converts text from one encoding to another encoding. It might be useful for a batch of files. `:)`